# Someone replaced console on some script and now I'm not able to use it

Tags: javascript

Just like the title said, some script in this webpage I'm working with does the following:
`window.console={},window.console.log=function(){}`

I am not allowed to remove that, but most of my code already uses console for logs and I don't want to change that, is there any way in which I can still use console? if it helps any, this will only run on chrome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a way, if you are able to run some of your code before the "bad" code.
Save the console-object to another variable, like:

```
window.cons = window.console;
```

then you can use console like:

```
window.cons.log('something');
```

Comment: I think OP wants to *specifically* use the name 'console'.

Comment: @mntgoat can you clarify?

Comment: I could switch names, I just need the console functionality, but I have no control over where my scripts get inserted so I can't save the  console object in another variable with 100% certainty that it will work.

Comment: another trick would be to add an dummy iframe to the dom and use the window of the iframe. because the iframe has an own window-object and does not load the other js-code, this should work. but its not sooo nice i would say...

Answer (score 0):

As long as this is just for debugging, and not production, you can inject an iframe and access it's console.

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
_console = {};
_console.log = function() {
    return iframe.contentWindow.console.log.apply(iframe.contentWindow.console, arguments)
}
```

this assumes that console functionality exists, though. It would throw an error where the console never existed. If you need to protect against that, you can just modify the log function to check for `iframe.contentWindow.console`s existence.

```
_console.log = function() {
    return iframe.contentWindow.console && iframe.contentWindow.console.log.apply(iframe.contentWindow.console, arguments)
}
```